# Xbox 360 doesn't work with HDMI

Tags: xbox-360, hdmi

So, my little sister got an Xbox 360 and the HDMI works for her TV, but when I moved it to my room it won't work for HDMI but it still works for hers I really want it to work for my TV and I want to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Please help me, this is the first gaming console I have had, and it's not working.

The things I have done are:

- Plugging it into the TV then plug it into the Xbox and turn then it on at the same time. I have done this 5 times without success.
- Using all of the different HDMI ports on my TV.

Comment: Have you tried plugging any other HDMI devices into your TV? Are you certain you changed the input source to the source the Xbox was hooked to? What kind of TV do you have? What kind of TV does your sister have?

Answer (score -1):

It probably is that your Xbox may not be working well and you should take it to a shop to be looked at. I have never personally had this problem so I can only recommend asking a professional and seeing what the problem is.